# Ionic2 - Cannot display local image on UI given its path

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I did [this](http://devfanaticblog.com/working-with-camera-in-ionic-2-and-ionic-native/) tutorial.

Everything was OK, but when selecting an image from the Gallery, the image `uri` was assigned to the `img` element via its attribute: `src` (`img[src]`). Then the image was displayed as broken.

I logged the image `URI` and got the following:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1792
```

Then, just for testing I overrided the `url` with the real path and also got a broken image. This was the real path I tried:

```
/storage/9016-4EF8/DCIM/Camera/20170422_202334.jpg
```

Then, my question is:
How do I get an image get displayed on the `ionic2 UI` using its path?

Maybe the problem is the embedded `webview` (like a normal browser) (`Ionic/Cordova`) doesn't have permissions to display local media for security reasons?. In that case, should be a way or plugin to solve this?

On the tutorial above the camera subexample worked OK because what was assigned to the image element was the content of the image in `base64` format, but I wanna make use of a `path` because I think it is more clear.

I tried some suggestions from the following link with no success. Maybe is an old link not suitable for the current platforms (or maybe the suggestions were OK and I did some mistake).
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/no-local-image-showing-in-view-on-device/30647

Here you have some information of my system:

```
$ npm -v
3.10.10

$ cordova -v
6.5.0

$ ionic info    
Your system information:    
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Any idea on how to get this work?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to using `sourceType: CAMERA. PHOTOLIBRARY` in android the uri is not able to be shown in img src attribute. To solve this problem use the following code to correct the image path.

```
    Camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
     // Correcting android photolibrary image page
     this.nativeFilePath = imagePath;
     if (this.pl.is('android') && sourceType === Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {
       FilePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath)
       .then(filePath => {
           this.nativeFilePath = filePath;
           let currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imagePath.lastIndexOf('?'));
       });
     } else {
       var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
     }
    }, err => {
     // this.presentToast('upload image fail.');
    });
```

hope this helps!